# Emgu imagebox docked in panel,when larger image is mapped some part of image is not shown even after scrolling to bottom right

Tags: c#, winforms, emgucv

I have a Emgu image box with autosize docked in panel with autoscroll when an image is larger in size of panel even after scrolling to bottom right some part of the image(vertically,horizontally) is not shown.please provide a solutionwhere whole image is shown even scrolling is applied and imagebox should be autosize.

Comment: Change to `ImageBox.Dock = none`, otherwise the ImageBox will show its own scrollbars. Dock the Panel container instead.